# Why I do not get the saved preference?

Tags: java, android

In one activity I save some data with this code:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getPreferences(4);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putString("myPhone",  mCountryCode + mPhone);
    editor.commit();
```

In another activity (in the same application) i try to retrieve the data:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getPreferences(4);
    myPhone=sharedPref.getString("myPhone", "");
```

But what I get out is an empty string!

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`Activity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getPreferences%28int%29) documentation:

> `public SharedPreferences getPreferences(int mode)`
>
> Retrieve a `SharedPreferences` object for accessing preferences that are private to this activity. This simply calls the underlying `getSharedPreferences(String, int)` method by passing in this activity's class name as the preferences name.

As the description says the preferences obtained with this method are private to the activity.

You need to use this method:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getSharedPreferences("YourApp", 4);
```

This gets preferences that are shared with each other. Documentation for that exact method can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getPreferences%28int%29). `"YourApp"` is the name of the preferences file, so it can be altered however you want, although it has to be the same with every use.

Answer (score 1):

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("your_file_name", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("yourStringName", "value_here");
editor.commit();
```

Access it using below code

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("your_file_name",
  MODE_PRIVATE); 
String string = prefs.getString("yourStringName",
  "default_value_here");
```

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure your mCountryCode and mPhone are not empty strings.

You are using getPreferences() with flag 4 (MODE_MULTI_PROCESS) which:

> This was the legacy (but undocumented) behaviour in and before Gingerbread (Android 2.3) and this flag is implied when targeting such releases

Use the following instead to save:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

editor.putString("myPhone",  mCountryCode + mPhone);
editor.commit();
```

And to load:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
myPhone = prefs.getString("myPhone", "");
```

More info [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_PRIVATE).